# Can you re-use child layouts?

Tags: java, android

Say I have a (programatically created) parent LinearLayout parent1 and I add a (programatically created) childA layout with `parent1.addView(childA);` then I set up childA in some complex way - perhaps it has its own children within it. Now can I subsequently somehow un-link it from parent1 without damaging any of the information within childA so that I can re-use it using parent2.addView(childA)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can!

You only need to guarantee you don't add it to another view before removing it from the previous parent.

**EDIT**:

```
// assuming a previously defined childA view
View childA;

parent1.removeView(childA);
parent2.addView(childA);
```

Comment: How is the "removing" done? Do I need to execute some function?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide an index when you add the view, you can get it back later:

```
int index = // whatever
parent1.addView(childA, index);
...
View child = parent1.getViewAt(index);
parent1.removeViewAt(index);
...
parent2.addView(child, index2);
```

Note also that the two parents must be either the same type of viewgroup OR you need to change the layoutParams of the child view to the appropriate type of the new parent